# Pycharm unresolved reference, even though the code using these "unresolved" references works just fine

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I've got a project. Pycharm reports unresolved references, even though the code using these "unresolved" references works just fine.

I've tried invalidate cachces/restart, Mark directory as Project root - nothing works. The funny thing is that is happened after pycharm restart. I just restarted my IDE and got the issue.

From this picture it can be seen that all directories and **init**.py files are indeed in place.

[image]

Comment: which file is the one shown on the right side of the picture?

Comment: this one is pipelines.py

Comment: hmm. in my experience if the other file (items.py) is in the same directory as the file you are importing from (pipelines.py), then why would you need to put "from EchoMskCrawler.items"? would "from items" not be sufficient?

Comment: Also, I am just a bit concerned about why there are two nested directories of the same name....

Comment: From the coloring, it looks like you have marked the inner `EchoMskCrawler` package as [re]sources root when the dotted paths of your imports indicate it should be the outer one.

Comment: Alright. You were right, too many nested folders. from items import blablab was enough. There are two equal directories cause one is github project and the other one was generated by scrapy. Do you want do make a separate answer so that i could accept it?

Comment: glad it got fixed. I added a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two nested folders of the same name: EchoMskCrawler. And pycharm is getting confused. Also, you only need to put:

```
from items import....
```

because they are in the same directory

Comment: That was exactly the case. For some reason I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3 you should do it:

```
from .items import SingleIssueItem
```